# PHP Mail Headers does not work?

Tags: php, email, email-headers

Whenever I have the headers added to `mail()`, the recipient does not receive any email.

This works ok:

```
// The message
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

// Send
mail('contact@xxx.net', 'My Subject 2', $message);
```

This is not ok:

```
// The message
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

// Send with headers
mail('contact@xxx.net', 'My Subject', $message, 'From: Test <test123@yahoo.co.uk>');
```

Any ideas why?

**EDIT:**

It seems that it is caused by the `@yahoo.co.uk` email addresses. It is ok with `@gmail.com`!

Why!??? Is it something to with my production server??

**EDIT 2:**

Same thing happens even though I use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer):

```
// Include Composer autoloader.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->setFrom('test123@yahoo.co.uk', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('contact@xxx.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

But it works ok with `@gmail.com`:

```
$mail->setFrom('test123@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
```

Comment: I know this is not an answer to your exact question, but have you considered using an existing library such as PHPMailer which takes care of this for you?

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Are you getting errors from PHP or within your OS logs such as syslog? That may tell you why.

Comment: I don't get any error from PHP. I can't see any error logs on my server - it is a shared hosting.

Comment: Are the message marked as spam in yahoo? The problem can be the diff in domain from smtp-sender to from-header.

Comment: @rogeriolino `Are the message marked as spam in yahoo?` nope. i haven't set any spam filter in my email account in my server.

Comment: Try to configure the smtp transport in PHPMailer, using the yahoo credential.

Comment: @rogeriolino i don't understand the smtp part. why using the yahoo credential?

Comment: By default PHPMailer use `mail` function. The test is setup yahoo smtp (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to check if your host server (default PHP mail configuration) is blocked by yahoo or not.

Answer (score 3):

More specifically to answer your question, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php Example 2 titled "Example #2 Sending mail with extra headers."

You need to add return/new lines for valid headers.

Comment: "Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF".  You shouldn't need to with a single header line.

Comment: I have tried with that example #2. It is still the same. I found a strange reason that causes the problem - see my edit above.